# serialize form data with ajax in jsp

Tags: ajax, jsp, serialization

I have a form with list of items (for example books)
each item has ID 
whenI send this form with ajax I can not get the bookID, it always give me the first ID not the selected one :(

the item displayed as table with hidden button to represent the bookID
I am new in ajax and jsp

any help will be appreciated
thank you

```
    <script>
    function sendRequestform(formid){



        var form= document.getElementById(formid);

         var dataString = $(form).serialize();

        console.log(dataString);
        alert(dataString);

$.ajax( {
    type: 'get',
    url: 'RequestBook',
    data: dataString,
    success: function(data) {
        alert("su");


        console.log(data);
        $('#bookSharedType').html(data);
        $('body').append(data);
    }
})
    // Set the tooltip content upon successful retrieval
   // api.set('content.text', content);
 ;


}




<table border="2" width="60%" align="center">
    <tr>

        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Author</th>

        <th>category</th>
        <th>status</th>
        <th>entedDate</th>


        <th>option</th>
    </tr>

    <c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">

        <tr>
            <td style="cursor: pointer;">${row.title}</td>
            <td>${row.auther}</td>
            <td>${row.category}</td>
            <td>${row.status}</td>
            <td>${row.enterdDate}</td>



            <td>

                <form action="RequestBook" method="post" name ="formNam" id="ff">
                    <input type="hidden" name="bookID" id="bookID" value="${row.bookID}">//here is the problem it always show me the ID for the first item

                    <input type="hidden" name="actionGetBookST" value="Request">
                    <input type="button" value="Book" onclick="sendRequestform('ff');"> // this call of the ajax
                </form>

        </td>


    </c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues i can see with your code,

1. HTML element ID should be unique, but you are having the form for every row with same id as 'ff' and even the form elements ids are duplicated
2. You really don't need a form here as you are not submitting it. You can just pass the bookId to the function `sendRequestform` and send the data to server

I can rewrite your code like below :

```
    <tr>
        <td style="cursor: pointer;">${row.title}</td>
        <td>${row.auther}</td>
        <td>${row.category}</td>
        <td>${row.status}</td>
        <td>${row.enterdDate}</td>
        <td><input type="button" value="Book" onclick="sendRequestform(${row.bookID});">
        </td>
```

```
function sendRequestform(bookId, pro){
    alert("book Id "+ bookId)
    $.ajax( {
        type: 'get',
        url: 'RequestBook',
        data: {"bookId" :bookId, "bookProvider" : pro},//append any other elements if you want to send
        success: function(data) {
            alert("su");
            console.log(data);
            $('#bookSharedType').html(data);
            $('body').append(data);
        }
    });
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I got that 
but in the servlet (java code )
how i can take that value (bookId)

I have this line 
        request.getParameter("bookID"))

and it give me the value of the first book again :(

Comment: System.out.println("[REQUESTED BOOK ID GET METHOD ] = " + request.getParameter("bookid"));

yes i see the update 
look at this line, it gives me null

Comment: what it is alerting when you click on the button?

Comment: the alert seems correct
here is the code after your updates
I just change the function name
         function getBookID(bookId) 
  {alert("bookId = "+bookId);
   
   $.ajax( {
         type: 'get',
         url: 'RequestBook',
         data: {"bookId=":bookId},//append any other elements if you want to send
         success: function(data) {
          
          alert("bookId = "+bookId);
          alert("su");
             console.log(data);
             $('#bookSharedType').html(data);
             $('body').append(data);
         }
     });

   }

Comment: "bookId=":bookId}, remove the colon here

Comment: sorry;
one more issue 
how can i append more that one attribute
I try this but it seems wrong
         data: {"bookId="+bookId ,"bookProvider="+pro},//append any other elements if you want to send

Comment: i found this 
         data: "bookId="+bookId + "&bookProvider="+pro,//append any other elements if you want to send

and it works 
thanks

Comment: if you want to get rid of adding &, updated the answer check it. thanks